# Java Cast New Instance from class name

Tags: java, casting

I want to do something like that:

```
MyObject mySuperObject = new MySuperObject();
String className = "NewClassName"; //the child object name´s from MySuperObject, received as a parameter in this method
Class<?> newClass= Class.forName(className);
NewClass newClass = (newClass) mySuperObject;
newClass.methodOfSuperClass();
```

Is this possible ? This method will receive any types of NewClassName...
I don't want to use ifs to select which class i'll use to cast the MySuperObject...

Comment: What you're asking doesn't really make sense. `methodOfClassName` is a statically-known method, which needs to be resolved at compile-time; but you're saying you want the class to be resolved at runtime. This just isn't how method invocation works.

Comment: Based on your “received as a parameter in this method” comment, I suspect you should not be passing a String as a parameter.  Instead, make your argument of type `Supplier<? extends MySuperObject>`, so calling code can pass `NewClass::new` as an argument.

Comment: Let me explain better: i want to receive a class type as an argument and cast an object with this received class type.